# Printing a string inconsistency

Tags: c, string, initialization, stack, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  char a[8];

  a[0] = 'h';
  a[1]='e';
  a[2]='l';
  /*a[3]='l';
  a[4]='o';*/

  printf("%s", a); 
}
```

When I run this program it prints out: hel

But why is it that when I have it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  char a[8];

  a[0] = 'h';
  a[1]='e';
  a[2]='l';
  a[3]='l';
  a[4]='o';

  printf("%s", a); 
}
```

It prints out: hello��

If the string is 3 characters or less, then it prints out the string correctly but if I have more than that and no NULL character at the end(to signify the end of the string) it prints out some garbage?

Also, this is in C.

Comment: a char array where no element is `'\0'` is not a string. If you use such an array where a string is expected you invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You are facing some unexpected behavior since you are not closing the string with a `NUL` `'\0'` character. In the first version when you skip the `[3]` address in the array it probably contains a `0` that fatally close the string, but this is absolutely random and unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

In C, dynamic (`malloc`...) and automatic (stack) variables are not zero-initialised. Only static and thread-local variables are zeroed.
Thus, if you do not provide the terminating 0 yourself, there might not be one, so your string is not terminated and using it results in undefined behavior.

Anyway, using indeterminate values can result in implementation defined or undefined behavior in certain cases all by itself, which might make your program misbehave erratically.